# How to know that function is getting value form which file(model or class)

Tags: magento-1.8

I am a little confused here I didn't understand what is this.

I have a `.phtml` file in which there is a function say `$this->getArticle()` when I print this it show the array of the data's stored in the database.

Then I have a function call like this `$this->getArticle()->getId()`, `$this->getArticle()->getContentHtml()` these shows the values which is inside the array as the under the same name as database field i.e `id` and `content_html`.

I understand till now.

But in the next line there is another function call like this `$this->getArticle()->getCategories()` It is returning the categories inside the my article array. But what I didn't understand is that from where is this `getArticle()` calls the value.
I dont have categories as an database field name.

In my class file I have a function defined as `function getArticle()` but there is no function named as `getCategories`.

Then I checked my model file and there I find the function `getCategories` which is actually returning the category values.

So the question is that, in the first two statement the the function is called from the `class file` while in the last one the same function `getArticle`is calling the model file and the next is the function in this file. how is this happen.

What is the logic behind this I didn't understand the flow here when to get value from model and when from class.

Comment: What is the class you are extending in Model?

Comment: `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` my model extends this class

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$this` inside a template file (one that has `.phtml` extenision) you are referring to the block of that template file.

So `getArticle()` probably returns an object of type Article and that object has a `getCategories()` method.

This is called **fluent interface**(http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-basics-of-fluent-interfaces-in-php/)

Comment: and what if we use `$this` in the block file, then `$this` is referring to what.

Comment: As you mentioned getArticle() return a model of type article. Now that model has a getCategories() method. Take a look at this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4170/class-calling-another-class